# How can i make a loop to show only the first 4 innings and then ask if they want to play again?

Tags: java, while-loop, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I have an assignment where im supposed to make a simulated baseball game using linked list. So far, i am able to print out all the batters and display how many runs/hits they had in the inning after 3 outs. The problem im having is that i should have a minimum of 4 innings and at least 1 score run in order to ask to play again. I cant figure out a way to make a loop to where it will display all innings with the score for each inning. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwuvU.png)is how it should look like as the final output and [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1coXl.png) is how mine is displayed. As you can see, it keeps asking if i want to play again after each inning and doesnt show the 2nd inning even though its printed out.

my code

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class baseball {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        baseball b = new baseball();
        b.addPlayer(1, "Ted Williams", .344, .0687);
        b.addPlayer(2, "Rogers Hornsby", .359, .0375);
        b.addPlayer(3, "Mark McGwire", .265, .095);
        b.addPlayer(4, "Babe Ruth", .340, .085);

        boolean keepGoing = true;
            while (keepGoing) {
                b.startGame();
                Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.printf("\nPlay again?: Y/N");
                if (s.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    keepGoing = false;
                }
            }
    }

    private void startGame() {
        int ct = 0;
        int inning = 0;
        int outs = 0;
        int hits = 0;
        int score = 0;
        int htct = 0;
        baseball.Players current = head;
        baseball.Players end = tail;

        System.out.printf("\n ------------- Inning: %s - Game Score: %s Runs", ++inning, score);
        while (outs != 3) {
            Random r = new Random();
            double rr = r.nextDouble();
            if (current.bAvg > rr) {
                System.out.printf("\n\nBatter %s - %s ->  BA: %s Random Number: %.2f HIT", ++ct, current.name, current.bAvg, rr);
                ++htct;
                if (htct >= 3) {
                    hits++;
                    score = hits;
                }
                end.next = head;
            } else if (current.hrAvg > rr) {
                System.out.printf("\n\nBatter %s - %s ->  BA: %s Random Number: %.2f HOMERUN", ++ct, current.name, current.bAvg, rr);
            } else if (current.bAvg < rr) {
                System.out.printf("\n\nBatter %s - %s ->  BA: %s Random Number: %.2f Miss", ++ct, current.name, current.bAvg, rr);
                outs++;
                if (outs == 3) {
                    System.out.printf("\n--------------- Inning Totals: %s Runs %s Hits", hits, htct);
                }
                end.next = head;
            }

            current = current.next;
        }
            System.out.printf("\n ------------ Inning: %s - Game Score: %s Runs", ++inning, score);
        }
    public class Players {
        public Integer bOrder;
        public String name;
        public Double bAvg;
        public Double hrAvg;
        Players previous;
        Players next;

        public Players(int bOrder, String name, Double bAvg, Double hrAvg) {
            this.bOrder = bOrder;
            this.name = name;
            this.bAvg = bAvg;
            this.hrAvg = hrAvg;
            this.next = null;
            this.previous = null;
        }
    }
    Players head, tail = null;

    public void addPlayer(int bOrder,String name, Double bAvg, Double hrAvg) {
        Players players = new Players(bOrder,name,bAvg,hrAvg);
        if (head == null) {
            //its the first node
            head = players;
            tail = players;
            head.previous = null;
            tail.next = null;

        } else {
            tail.next = players;
            players.previous = tail;
            tail = players;
            tail.next = null;

        }
    }

}
```

i tried adding the keepGoing loop into my method but it still doesnt seem to work out and it becomes an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Add game counter and increment it every time after every start game..
modified while (keepGoing) :

```
    int numberOfGames = 0;    \\ initialize game counter
                while (keepGoing) {
                    b.startGame();
                    numberOfGames++; \\ increment counter when game is played
                    if(numberOfGames==3) \\ if 3 then offer play again option
                    {
                          Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.printf("\nPlay again?: Y/N");
                    if (s.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                        keepGoing = false;
                    } else 
numberOfGames =0; // reset counter if want to play 

                    }
                    
                  
                }
```